# TTS works only if using "en_US" language

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I can't make TTS speak on any language different from `en_US`. If I try to use e.g. `en_GB`, then `speak()` doesn't generate any sound and returns immediately.

The language data is installed correctly. I've got **Google Text-to-speech Engine** on the device. Also I tried to use another app (**Pocket**), and it worked perfectly with any language.

My code is simple:

```
OnInitListener listener = new OnInitListener() {
  public void onInit(int status) {
    tts.setLanguage(Locale.UK); // returns LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE
    tts.speak("Hello world", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
  }
};
TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(activity, listener, "com.google.android.tts");
```

As you can see, `setLanguage()` returns `LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE`, but it doesn't matter.

I've tried many languages, but nothing's changed:

```
tts.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
tts.setLanguage(Locale("spa", "ESP"));
tts.setLanguage(tts.getAvailableLanguages().iterator().next());
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `setLanguage(new Locale("eng", "GBR"))`

Comment: @brandall Just tried. The same result. But thanks anyway

Comment: When you go to the Android Text to Speech Settings and change the voice to UK, does 'listen to a sample' work? Is the result of `onInit` `SUCCESS`? Don't use null in `speak()`, use the API correctly, otherwise it will cause more problems for you once you solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check for that language availability.
It will return `TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE` to indicate that the language AND country as described by the Locale parameter are supported (and the data is correctly installed).

```
tts.isLanguageAvailable(new Locale("spa", "ESP")))
```

Also note that besides the `ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA` intent to check the availability of the TTS data, you can also use `isLanguageAvailable()` once you have created your TextToSpeech instance, which will return `TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA` if the required resources are not installed for the queried language.

Making the engine speak an Italian string while the engine is set to the French language will produce some pretty interesting results, but it will not exactly be something your user would understand So try to match the language of your application's content and the language that you loaded in your TextToSpeech instance. Also if you are using `Locale.getDefault()` to query the current Locale, make sure that at least the default language is supported.